# Prawn - Table - ascii code - Pdf generation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, prawn

I'm using prawn to generate pdfs.
In one of my tables, I would like to insert a checkmark via html code (ascii) -> [☒ or ☐].
I tried to  use HTMLEntities gem but doesn't work in views, just on IRB. And html_safe either.
On the pdf, there is just a '_' character (underscore).

I'm am in utf-8.
Any ideas why? Is there another solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your font doesn't include these glyphs. Use a font that does:

```
require 'prawn'
Prawn::Document.generate('checkmarks.pdf') do |pdf| 
  pdf.font("/Library/Fonts/Arial Unicode.ttf") # adjust font path
  pdf.text("☒ ☐")
end
```

Comment: Cool. I now see what i have to do. But, i have the "No such file or directory" error and when i use just :font => "Arial Unicode", tells me that he doesn't know that font. The server is running on rails 2. I don't have the assets directory, but can i download the font somewhere ?

Comment: [Arial Unicode MS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arial_Unicode_MS) comes with Microsoft Office and Mac OS X. However, any font including the checkmark glyphs will do.

Comment: I am currently working on ubuntu. Thank you for your help. I'll try something else if I don't find a solution.